# In Firebase, How do I prevent memory-modification cheats (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have **Users** table in Firebase. However, users can change our scores, etc. How can i handle this situation ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase your question or add detail? It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In general I recommend storing the actual moves that a user has made in the game, in addition to the score they achieved. At the very least you can then replay those moves to see if the score is correct or manipulated. But you can also further analyze the moves to see if they were made by the player or seem synthesized.

You can use [Firebase's security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to validate the moves of certain games. But depending on the game this may be beyond what you're willing to write security rules for. In that case, you should write the (move and score) validation into a back-end process that runs in a trusted environment. This may be a an app server you control, but it also be as simple as a process you periodically run on your own machine.

Some links that cover the same/a similar topic:

- [Firebase complex validation](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/14ad3k9b28/firebase-firebase-complex-validation)
- [Firesafe: Add Complex Security Logic to Your Firebase App](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/02/firesafe-add-complex-security-logic-to.html)
- [can Firebase be used to backend Unity MMOs?](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/can-firebase-be-used-to-backend-unity-mmos.173675/)